# Looking to make spreadsheet into applet, widget, or API

Tags: html

I have two similar but different projects. Both I would like to take something I created as an excel spreadsheet and make into something I can embed in a website. I am mostly asking what language would be best, any resources for learning how that language, or any insights. I will post the exact nature of the projects below just in case there is any relevance.
Thanks!

For the first project, I have a spreadsheet where a I can insert values into A1 and A2 and get a result in A3. This is based on many formulas. I would like to make this into something I can put online so the user can only see three values and not the formulas. 
For the second project I have a large spread sheet that is 1000x1000. Each row and column corresponds to a name. Right now once again I can put a name in A1 a name in A2 and get the value in A3. I would like to make this into something I can put online.

Comment: Maybe the title can be optimised? "Complete newbie but willing to learn." isn't really necessary (at least not for the title) :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to have it actually be functional, or are you interested in posting just the results?

If you want functionality then for the first project a simple javascript will suffice (learn jquery - a wrapper that makes javascript easier)

For 1000x1000 you're gonna have to explain exactly what the functionality is that you're looking for.

**Edit**: Google Docs supports some sorts of [widget/gadget](http://www.widgetslab.com/2008/03/22/google-docs-spreadsheets-now-with-gadgets/) deal. Learn that, and use Google spreadsheet to do your math for you.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Javascript (the calculations are done on the client)

Option 2: PHP (the calculations are done on a web server)

both are free and you can find plenty of resources you can start with  http://www.w3schools.com/